# Successful issue report, but no issues on dashboard

Tags: c#, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

I am currently looking to add code analysis to a C# project.  I'm running the analysis through Jenkins/C#/Visual Studio plugins and am not getting any issues reported on the dashboard.  My issue JSON report has lots of the following issues:

```
{
   "ruleId":"CS7035",
   "level":"warning",
   "message":"The specified version string does not conform to the recommended format - major.minor.build.revision",
   "locations":[
      {
         "resultFile":{
            "uri":"my file",
            "region":{
               "startLine":123,
               "startColumn":22,
               "endLine":123,
               "endColumn":33
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "properties":{
      "warningLevel":4
   }
},
...
```

Clearly the analysis is working and generating the issues.  However when I view the project on the dashboard, it shows no bugs/vulnerabilities/etc.  Interestingly, it does show the lines of code and duplication statistics.

The analysis does work for our JS code, so it seems to just be a C# thing.

Comment: Can you please post the whole analysis log? (maybe on pastebin.org to make it more convenient) It's impossible to answer w/o it.

Comment: Where can I find the analysis log?  Would it be in .sonarqube folder in the generated workspace or would it be in my sonarqube instance itself?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right log or not but this is the full json I got the message above from: http://pastebin.com/AFyef0C0.  Let me know if there's another log you're looking for.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm taking about the console output when you invoke "MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin" and then "MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end"

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense.  Here is my console log from Jenkins.  http://pastebin.com/vBGnCN1G.  Let me know if I can send anything else.  I had to remove a few of the same messages from the log to reduce file size at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using version 5.3 of the C# plugin that does not support the new version of the SARIF JSON format.

This was fixed in version 5.3.1 - see [SONARCS-602](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS-602).

Updating to this last version of the plugin should fix your issue.

Comment: Very interesting.  I know for a fact I checked for updates in the update center yesterday and didn't see any.  Perhaps I'm crazy because it was there today.  I can confirm that this resolved the issue for me and I am now seeing the bugs/code smells on the sonarqube dashboard.